# How to write a custom exception for TemplateView and APIView in Django which will return custom error for request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have written

```
class CustomApiException(APIException):

    #public fields
    detail = None
    status_code = None

    # create constructor
    def __init__(self, status_code, message):
        #override public fields
        CustomApiException.status_code = status_code
        CustomApiException.detail = message
        CustomApiException.message = message
```

which is working for APIView but for TemplateView it gives error. What is the proper way to write custom API Exception which will work for both views.

Comment: Using Django 1.11 and Django Rest Framework 3.6.3

Comment: Could you tell us what error it is giving so it would give us more information on where you are going wrong, Edit the question by adding stack trace of the error to it

Comment: Thanks Anuj for update the question properly....

Comment: Problem is when i am using json call in ajax I am able to return proper error message with custom status code...... but when request is text/HTML i am not able to archive the same

Comment: I think you mean that, the behaviour isnt right when you do the request through browser, right? If yes, What exactly happens when you try to send a get request through browser?

Comment: It give me a default template in response. with status code 403

Comment: I have answered the question, assuming that you want to raise a 403 Error,
If that isnt what you expect, please tell me what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views define the template view as following

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

#rest of the views
class yourview(TemplateView):
    def get(request):
        try:
            #business logic
        except CustomApiException:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

This will raise a `Error 403`

If you want to render your own template instead of raising `HttpResponseForbidden`, you could pass the exception variables to the view in following way and write the response of the view appropriately

```
class yourview(TemplateView):
    def get(request):
        try:
            #business logic
        except CustomApiException as e:
            status_code = e.status_code
            detail = e.message
            message = e.message
            #Handle the response here.
```